# Not able to rate or review apps

Tags: store, 7.8

I am from India and using Nokia lumia 710 device. Right now, I am running updated 7.8 OS but the problem persisted earlier too.

The issue is that whenever I try to post rating and review about any app, nothing happens. The review page disappears as soon as I tap submit. Nothing is posted there. Why is this happening.

Comment: has anyone else experienced this issue. Please let me know. I just can't rate an application on my phone. Feels frustrating.

Comment: Still not able to rate apps after 8862. Has someone else faced a similar issue

Comment: When I review an app, I am not able to see my review in the list for a up to a couple days... Have you checked up on apps you tried to review before to see if they are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a Samsung Focus and notice that too. But for my surprise the comment and rating show up in the app later. Give a try. Check back if the app you rated has your comment hour after.

The behavior of Windows Phone 8 is different. It waits in the screen while posting.

Comment: It waits on 7.5 or 7.8 too. The screen doesn't disapperar instantly as its happening now

Comment: Strange. Mine always disappear just after I click submit.

Comment: it rates the app. But doesn't shows what i rated and wrote in the review.

Comment: Even if you check one day after? Because I know it's not instant.

Comment: yaa..Even after days or months. I have rated every application i use but can't see it on my device. Yes on laptop I can see the review on windows phone store website.

Comment: Nokia Lumia 720. Same problem. Does does not publish review

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you try back a few days later. Reviews usually take time to process and show on the Store, depending on which country your Microsoft account is set to.

Also check that the country on your account is the same one as on your device. When writing a review, it's assigned to the country on your account. When reading reviews, you may be seeing the ones for the country on your device (it makes sense to show local ones), therefore you may not see your own if the two countries don't line up.