# App Rating and Review not showing

Tags: store, windows-8

I am new to the Windows platform, I have created and uploaded a Windows Phone application [Create Todo](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/create-todo/9nblgggz5r3q)

**It shows up in the store and all, but I am unable to see the user reviews and ratings** (Few of my friends have downloaded and reviewed ). Any help? I read that i have to wait a few hours, it's been hours long did i miss anything ?

PS: [I found this question but wasn't satisfied](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1515/not-able-to-rate-or-review-apps)

Comment: Where are you looking for the ratings? On your dev center dashboard or the store page?

Comment: both, dev center dash and store page

Comment: It can take up to 24 hours to show up..

Comment: I guess then i will wait for 24hrs and see , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually takes about 24h for reviews to show up, sometimes even longer. This is due to the refresh cycle of the store.

Comment: "This is die to..." @Thomas The Store isn't dying ;)

Comment: Or is it? ;-) kidding, guess I forgot to switch auto-correct to english :D

Comment: Well... Let's say it's not :)

Comment: Am "Dying" over here for the review to show up @Thomas

Comment: I know that feeling ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Rating and reviews are displayed based on country region  check the rate and review with en-in , en-us , en-gb ......

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/create-todo/9nblgggz5r3q

Comment: The question was about a developer point-of-view, not as a user.